# How do you delete multiple fields in a mongodb(mongoose odm) document but not the entire document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to delete only specific fields in my mongoDb user document but i don't think using the userModel.deleteOne({_id:id}) would not suffice as this would delete the entire document which isn't what i want.

```
{
    "_id": "12345678" ,
    "maidenName": null,
    "createdAt":  "2021-09-16T09:11:55.199Z" ,
    "email": "287983@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "iam1234",
    "lastName": "test14",
    "profile": "hello-world.com",
    "uid": "SKkZZ3a",
    "skills": []
}
```

I tried doing this `UserModel.updateOne({_id:id},{$unset:{email: 1, firstName: 1}});`
This query returns

```
{
  n: 0,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime: {
    ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1631832363 },
    t: 24
  },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000018,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1631832363 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1631832363 }
}
```

I've got no idea what this is! how best to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working, and its the right way to do it.
(you dont need to put 1, any value would be ok, like even "")

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BzyhmRESR-6)

This is telling you what happened

- n: 0   => no matching documents found
- nModified: 0 => no documents were updated

I think its the filter, probably simple mistake like wrong type of id?
Try a find alone, to see if you can find it